# how to over write file name in $request array with new name in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I want to insert data using create($request->all()) eloquent method but the problem is $request->all() contain a  file name   that is  default original file name from the form but i change  this actual file name as time() stamp  so  i use  $request->request->add(['image' =>$filename]);  but after insertion database contain a temp   file name.How i update filename in  $request array.

```
$filename=time().'.'.$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$request->file('image')->move(public_path().'/marriagepackage/',$filename);
$request->request->add(['image' =>$filename]);
$package=Marriagepackage::create($request->all());
```

When i check table then image field as "D:\xamp\tmp\php50C7.tmp"  actual my expected value is time() stamp value inside the  $filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to overwrite things with the request. It's not really a good idea. In your case you can just merge the request array with your property:

```
$package = Marriagepackage::create(array_merge($request->all(), [ "image" => $filename ]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way

```
$request->request->add([
    "image" => $filename
]);
```